# Should unit of work create repository?

Tags: dependency-injection, solid, repository, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Our "unit of work" class has a method which takes a class type and creates a repository:

```
public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            var repoItem = _repositoryList.FirstOrDefault(cv => cv.GetType().IsGenericType && cv.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(TEntity));
            if (repoItem == null)
            {
                repoItem = new Repository<TEntity, object>(Context);
                _repositoryList.Add(repoItem);
            }
            return repoItem as IRepository<TEntity>;
        }
```

For me, it looks very strange because the unit of work is not DI.

I tried to explain it to my team, but they always say "all examples of unit of work contain concrete classes, or properties/methods which can create and return repositories."

But my opinion about a "unit of work" is, it should know only what repositories exist, and when I call `Savechanges`, it should save the entities in all these repositories.

Now our services contructors takes only `UnitOfWork`, but my opinion is, it should take also the repository interfaces. Because UnitOfWork shouldn't be a God class which can do anything.

Do you have some good explanation why it is wrong\right?

Answer (score 5):

The immediate problem I see here that it becomes hard to unit test the "UnitOfWork" with mock repositories. What if the line

```
    repoItem = new Repository<TEntity, object>(Context);
```

needs to be replaced by  ... `new MockRepository` for a meaningful test?

So in case `UnitOfWork` just needs one or two, maybe 3 repos, you could try to inject them in the `UnitOfWork` constructor. If it needs more, but the repos can be instantiated beforehand, then you could also try to inject the filled `_repositoryList` beforehand, without extending it in `UnitOfWork`.

However, if your `UnitOfWork` is really so complex it requires to utilize lots of different repo classes, and creating the repos should be done only "on demand" (as shown in your example), then I would try the following: create a new class `RepositoryFactory` which encapsulates `_repositoryList`, refactor `GetRepository` to this new class, and inject an object of type `IRepositoryFactory` into the `UnitOfWork`. That gives you the necessary separation of reponsibilities, and will allow to inject a `MockRepositoryFactory` for a unit test.